# Front and Back Wheel Revolutions

Tags: geometry

Here is a problem that I am stuck on: On an old-fashioned bicycle the front wheel has a radius of $2.5$ feet and the back wheel has a radius of $4$ inches. If there is no slippage, how many revolutions will the back wheel make while the front wheel makes $100$ revolutions?

So, the front wheel has circumference 2*2.5* $\pi$ = 5 $\pi$. That means it moves 5*100 = 500 $\pi$ after 100 revolutions.

Then we divide this by 2*4 = 8 $\pi$ which is equal to 62.5. So the back wheel moves this many revolutions? Why am I wrong?

Comment: You need to work entirely in feet or entirely in inches.  You have mixed your units so your answer is wrong.

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't even see they were different units! Thank you so much!